# Uncaught TypeError: Request.callPost is not a function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My code it work, but if I call in html it don't work, I don't understand.
if I call in html it give me errors

> Uncaught TypeError: Request.call Post is not a function

why?

```
<button onclick="Request.callPost('/Api/Page/start/','mypost')" >My button</button>
<br> <br><br>
(function($){   
$(document).ready(function(){

    var Request={
        init:function(){

            this.callPost('/Api/Page/all','data'); //ok it work 
        },
        callPost:function(link,data){
            $.ajax({
                url:link,
                type:'POST',
                data:data,
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    return response;
                }
            });
        },
        callGet:function(link,data){
            $.ajax({
                url:link,
                type:'GET',
                data:data,
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response){
                    return response;
                }
            });
        },
    }

    Request.init();
})
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, your code is structured like this:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var Request = 'something';

    });
})(jQuery);

// trying to use 'Request' here
```

You can't use `Request` in global scope because it doesn't exist in global scope.  It exists only within the `function` you passed to the `ready()` function, which is also happening within another anonymous function.  Nothing outside of these functions can see that variable.

If you *need* your variable to exist in global scope, you can declare it there:

```
var Request;

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        Request = 'something';

    });
})(jQuery);

// you can use 'Request' here
```

Be careful with this approach as you generally don't want to just move everything to global scope any time you encounter an error.  This is *not* a golden hammer you want to get used to using.  If you *need* `Request` to be in global scope, this would do the trick.

As an alternative, consider instead attaching your click handler *within the scope where `Request` is available*.  Something like this:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var Request = /.../;

        $('#yourButton').click(Request.callPost('/Api/Page/start/','mypost'));

    });
})(jQuery);

// no need to use 'Request' here
```

There are *probably* some changes you'd have to make based on structure of your code outside what's being asked in this question, but the *principle* in this case should make sense.  Rather than having code in global scope (the HTML inline handler in your case) try to access code in a narrow scope, flip that around and have the code in the narrow scope access the objects in global scope (the HTML element in your case).

As code complexity grows and testability becomes more important, you'll want to abstract the global object entirely and *provide* it to the narrow-scoped code, rather than seek it out from within that narrow scoped code.  But we could spend hours going into that sort of thing and I think it's well outside what's being asked here.

Essentially what you're trying to do is access something in a narrow scope.  And the immediate solution would be to either put that something into a larger scope or change how you're structuring your code so that you don't need to access it in the first place.  The former is a quicker approach for just the code you're showing, the latter is cleaner.